# qmake searching for library in absolute path

Tags: qt, arm, cross-compiling, ld, buildroot

I am cross-compiling a Qt Application. My host is a Ubuntu system and target is ARM board with buildroot based filesystem and I am using Qt 5.3.1. When I try to run make, I get the following error:

```
/home/hamzah/vibrante/toolchains/tegra-4.8.1-nv/usr/bin/armv7a-vfpv3-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv7a-vfpv3-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0
/home/hamzah/vibrante/toolchains/tegra-4.8.1-nv/usr/bin/armv7a-vfpv3-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/armv7a-vfpv3-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see, it is using absolute path in target for `libpthread.so.0` and `libpthread_nonshared.a`. This library is placed in the target filesystem hosted on my host. The target library search path has been added in `qmake.conf` using `QMAKE_LIBDIR` variable:

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR  += /home/hamzah/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot
QMAKE_LIBDIR  += /home/hamzah/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib
```

I need to know how to make the `ld` able to find this library using `sysroot` variable or any other approach.

PS: I am compiling Qt Application. Pre-built Qt applications are running on both my host and target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the qmake built by Buildroot in output/host/usr/bin. This one has the right paths pre-configured. If it still doesn't work, please submit a bug report in the Buildroot bug tracker, with a simple test case to reproduce the problem, as well as the list of steps to reproduce it.

Comment: It built everything so quickly that I got skeptic of it. Worked like a charm

Comment: _LFLAGS = --sysroot=paht/to/ur/sysroot_ in Makefile, this was what I was looking for!! I still don't know where it is specified in qmake.conf tho, but the compilation works with it